# How to access Static Pages in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Springs. I created a program to access static pages from the folder.
When, I click on the button to access the static page. It is throwing 404 error.
Can some one let me know where exactly it is going wrong.Below is my code.
                          webcontroller.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
           import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
           import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
@Controller
        public class WebController {
        @RequestMapping(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index()
    {
        return "index";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/staticPage", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirect()
    {
        return "redirect:pages/final.html";
    }

}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring Static Pages</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Spring Static Landing page</h2>
<p>Click below button to get a simple HTML page</p>
<form action="/StaticPageEg/staticPage" method="GET">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="submit" value="Get HTML Page"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Final.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Simple HTML PAge</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

StaticPageEg-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.StaticPageEg"></context:component-scan>

 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

 <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
 <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
 </bean>

 <mvc:resources location="pages/" mapping="pages/**"/>
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>

 </beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name> Spring Static Pages</display-name>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>StaticPageEg</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>StaticPageEg</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Is your controller class under com.StaticPageEg package?

Comment: @ B.K : yes, it is in com.StaticPageEg

Comment: What is the path when you make that request?

Answer (score 0):

Map the `DispatcherServlet` to a certain pattern (e.g. *.do) so that it won't be hit when you access the static file using its path

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>StaticPageEg</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

...

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index.do", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

If you want to serve the page with dynamic content, make sure that the requests end with ".do". Else, just make sure that it is outside WEB-INF folder so that it is exposed to the public and therefore can be accessed through its path.

Comment: I changed according to your suggestion. But, Index page is not getting executed. If it is changed to *.do

Comment: You should modify your request to "/index.do" so that it will be mapped there.

Comment: yes, I modified as per your suggestion in both controller class and in servlet.xml file. But, I am getting 404 error. while executing.

Comment: What I mean is you should access your index page by something like `http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.do`

Comment: I made the changes in both the files i.e. in controller and servlet.xml file. And made the changes in url  while executing i.e http://localhost:8080/StaticPageEg/index.do. but it is throwing error when clicking on button. Error thrown is 404 "The requested resource (/StaticPageEg/staticPage) is not available." In error it is showing wrong path when, changes are made as mentioned above.

Comment: Its because the form action is still mapped to `/StaticPageEg/staticPage`. Change it to `pages/final.html`. You won't need the mapping to `/staticPage` anymore because Spring controller should not see your request to static file.

Comment: I made the changes as suggested. But again it is resulting in an error after clicking on the button. Error is 404 "The requested resource (/StaticPageEg/pages/final.html) is not available." I am not able to make out where it is going wrong.

Comment: Instead of `<form action="/StaticPageEg/staticPage" method="GET">` change it to `<form action="pages/final.html" method="GET">`

Comment: Make sure that `final.html` is really located under `pages` folder which is directly under your root directory. Check the deployed war.